# Shotcode argument issues

Tags: functions, shortcode

```
function some_function_bbb() {
        ob_start();
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'hexabexa'        => 0
            ), $atts )
         );
         $args = array(
            'hexabexa'        => $hexabexa
        );
        ?>


        <div class="newsletter <?php echo $args['hexabexa']==1 ? 'newsletter2' : '' ?>">
            <h2>Plugin Works!</h2>            
        </div>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('some_function_bbb', 'some_function_bbb');
```

Shortcode →

```
[some_function_bbb hexebexa="1"] →
```

still the class newsletter2 is not printing. where am i wrong?

Comment: Your shortcode should not `echo` anything; it should `return` the text you want to appear. See [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/).

Comment: @PatJ Are you sure ? Cause in the code `ob_get_clean()` used. Please notice. Also have a look to my answer. I think the problem is somewhere else. BTW, I tested my answer.

Comment: Let me clarify: The WordPress Way is to `return` the content of the shortcode, not `echo` it. There are always workarounds, but if you want to future-proof your code, your best bet is to do it properly.

Comment: @PatJ Retuning the obejct buffer is perfectly reasonable for a shortcode.

Comment: I stand corrected. Apparently my eyes skipped right over the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$atts` as parameter to the function. Also you don't need to use `extract()` function and better you avoid this `extract` function as much as you can. So your whole code block will be-

```
function some_function_bbb( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'hexabexa' => 0
        ),
        $atts
    );

    ob_start();
    ?>


    <div class="newsletter <?php echo $atts['hexabexa'] == 1 ? 'newsletter2' : '' ?>">
        <h2>Plugin Works!</h2>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('some_function_bbb', 'some_function_bbb');
// Call it like [some_function_bbb hexabexa=1]
```

And lastly you are passing your shortcode attribute wrong. You declared your attribute as `hexabexa` and passing the attribute as `hexebexa`.  The *e* should be *a* in your shortcode. So fix this typo also.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem was I was not passing $atts. Thanks, sir.